# Prove that two of the patches are such that their intersection covers at least $\dfrac {1}{5}$ of the whole area of the jeans.

Tags: combinatorics

Jack's jeans have 5 patches, each of which covers at least $\dfrac {1}{2}$
of the whole area of the jeans. Prove that two of the patches are such that their
intersection covers at least $\dfrac {1}{5}$ of the whole area of the jeans.

What should I do in order to solve this problem? Should I use the inclusive-exclusive formula? If so, what I do with the intersection by 3 patches, by 4 patches, and by 5 patches?

Comment: It seems to me that you only need three such patches, and already you are guaranteed that the intersection of two of them covers at least $\frac14$ of the whole area. Are you sure you have the question right?

Comment: Maybe if patch B is in between patch A and patch C, then for those area, patch A and patch C are not counted intersected.

Comment: @TonyK no: with three sets, $1/6$ can be obtained (so $1/4$ is not optimal). Example: $A=[0,1/2],B=[0,1/6]∪[1/2,5/6],C=[1/6,1/3]∪[2/3,1].$

Answer (score 0):

I'm "nearly there" (hopefully this post nudges someone else to find a complete answer [or counterexample]).

Firstly, I'd like to note that four patches are insufficient (at first, it seems that three patches would suffice, but this is not true).  Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $6$ equal-length segments $\{I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4,I_5,I_6\}$.  Then take

- $A=I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3$,
- $B=I_1 \cup I_4 \cup I_5$,
- $C=I_2 \cup I_4 \cup I_6$, and
- $D=I_3 \cup I_5 \cup I_6$.

We see that $\mu(X \cap Y)=\tfrac{1}{6}$ for all distinct $X,Y \in \{A,B,C,D\}$.

---

Now, I can't prove, for $\geq 5$ sets, the an intersection of size $\geq \tfrac{1}{5}$ exists, but below I prove $\geq \tfrac{1}{6}$.  I feel there should be a slick answer to this question.

Suppose we have a family of subsets $K$ of measure $\tfrac{1}{2}$.  Define $$a=\max_{(X,Y) \in K^2:X \neq Y} \mu(X \cap Y).$$  Further, suppose the maximum is achieved by $X$ and $Y$.

Then any $Z \in K \setminus \{X,Y\}$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\tfrac{1}{2} &= \mu(Z) \\
 &=\mu(Z \cap (X \setminus Y))+\mu(Z \cap (Y \setminus X))+\mu(Z \setminus (X \cup Y)) \\
 & \leq \mu(Z \cap X) + \mu (Z \cap Y) + \mu(E \setminus (X \cap Y)) \\
 & \leq a+a + (1-2 \times \tfrac{1}{2}+a) \\
 & = 3a.
\end{align*}
Hence we have $a \geq \tfrac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Why is $\mu(E \setminus (X \cap Y)) \le 1-2\times\frac12+a$? Surely $\mu(E \setminus (X \cap Y))=1-a$?